# Impossible to select edge loops with shortcut

Tags: modeling, edges, select, loop

In Blender 2.8 it's impossible to select edge loops with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> and left (or right) click. Why?

Comment: Je suis sous windows 10

Answer (score 2):

You've likely enabled *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* in the preferences (*Edit > Preferences > Input*). The shortcut doesn't work with this option enabled.

When the emulation is enabled, you can select edge loops by double clicking on the edges. If you hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> you can add additional edge loops by double clicking on another edge. For selecting edge rings hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and double click (*).

In case you don't need to emulate a 3 button mouse, you can disable the option in the preferences. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd> for right-click select) can then be used to select a single loop and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> (or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd>) for multiple edge loops, with the option to toggle the selection.

[image: Option in preferences]

(*) This option was added in commit [bb70594c1bc2a3c859c45fcd35776327be5e8e04](https://developer.blender.org/rBbb70594c1bc2a3c859c45fcd35776327be5e8e04), which was missing when the [original question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122333/selecting-multiple-edge-loops-in-blender-2-8) was posted.

Comment: It is unchecked by default right?

Comment: @Yash yes it should be disabled by default.