# how to change user preference in blender version 2.81

Tags: properties

i just downloaded blender 2.81. I'm very new to blender. I'm using blender on a laptop and I know that some settings are different if you don't have a mouse (which I don't.) I've learnt online that you're supposed to change the user preferences. From what I've read, you should type %appdata% in the windows search box and find the app data file (which I did), and i did find the user preference window  (userpref.blend) thing. Problem is, I don't know how to change the user preference after I've gotten into the window. Can someone kindly tell me what I should do next? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The preferences can be edited within Blender. For 2.8x they are located in *Edit > Preferences*. More information can be found in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/index.html).

[image: Preferences]

Comment: Note also that the settings to modify the input peripherals' behaviour are in "Navigation" and "Keymap" Tabs

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: Since you're working on a laptop you likely want to enable the *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* option in the *Input* tab, which allows you to rotate the 3D View through Alt+RMB. Please be aware that this changes the shortcuts for other commands that use the Alt key, for instance the [edge loop selection](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158669/impossible-to-select-edge-loops-with-shortcut/158692#158692).

Comment: @bug if this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark.